# Pegar Valor do Array PHP

Tags: php, array

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => #EXTM3U
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => #EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="BBB 18 -Aquecimento" tvg-logo"https://s9.postimg.org/4c14egx5b/big_welcome_Pic_4-300x169.png" group-title="Canais Globo",BBB 18 -Aquecimento (...)
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://infinity.quor8.com:8000/live/N708Kwo02j/qsTfBzzoPk/12664.ts
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => #EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="Globo RJ FHD" tvg-logo="http://i.imgur.com/NSHvLCe.png" group-title="Canais Globo",Globo RJ FHD
        )
)
```

Tenho esse array acima e preciso pegar somente o valor de **tvg-logo**

Tentei dessa forma aqui: `$array[2][tvg-logo];`

Mas o resultado foi esse:

```
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="BBB 18 -Aquecimento" tvg-logo="https://s9.postimg.org/4c14egx5b/big_Welcome_Pic_4-300x169.png" group-title="Canais Globo",BBB 18 -Aquecimento
```

como eu disse eu preciso somente do valor de **tvg-logo**

Alguém pode ajudar ?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função de **parser** e salvar cada parte da String do array em uma variável, usando a função:

```
void parse_str ( string $encoded_string [, array &$result ] )
```

No seu caso:
Acessando o valor de **$array[0][2]**

Você tem: **"EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="BBB 18 -Aquecimento" tvg-logo="https://s9.postimg.org/4c14egx5b/big_Welcome_Pic_4-300x169.png" group-title="Canais Globo",BBB 18 -Aquecimento";**

Com isso você pode:

```
parse_str($suaString, $resultado);

...
echo $resultado['tvg-id']; // ""
echo $resultado['tvg-name']; // "BBB 18 -Aquecimento
echo $resultado['tvg-logo']; // https://s9.postimg.org/4c14egx5b/big_Welcome_Pic_4-300x169.png
...
```

Comment: Olá BSants, obrigado pela ajuda, não tenho muita experiencia com isso, você poderia me dizer como fazer isso no php, tentei reproduzir oq vc disse mas não tive sucesso

Comment: Olá, é só colocar o código dentro da tag do php **<?php ?>**, se precisar, dê uma olhada na documentação: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php. De resto é só manipular o resultado do seu $array. Você pode salvar o resultado em uma nova variável $suaString = $array[0][2] como no exemplo.

Comment: Olha como eu fiz:

$string = $array;
  
    echo "</pre>";
 
 parse_str($string, $resultado);


echo $resultado['tvg-id']; // ""
echo $resultado['tvg-name']; // "BBB 18 -Aquecimento
echo $resultado['tvg-logo']; // 

ele retornar: Warning: parse_str() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/u805601857/public_html/canais1.php on line 43

Comment: Você pode utilizar um **var_dump()** http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php na variável para ver se realmente está recebendo o que é esperado, porém ele acusa erro na _linha 43_. Teste a mesma coisa apenas com:`tvg-id="" tvg-name="BBB 18 -Aquecimento" tvg-logo="https://s9.postimg.org/4c14egx5b/big_Welcome_Pic_4-300x169.png"`

Comment: Olha como eu fiz dessa vez: 
`code
 $string_antiga = $array[2][0];

parse_str($string_antiga , $resultado);

echo $resultado['tvg-id'];
echo $resultado['tvg-name'];
echo $resultado['tvg-logo'];


`
Mas ele não retorna resultado nenhum.

Comment: Não seria **$array[0][2] ??** Outra forma seria usar a função **explode()** http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php demarcando após o sinal de **=**. `$string_antiga = "tvg-id="" tvg-name="BBB 18 -Aquecimento" tvg-logo="https://s9.postimg.org/4c14egx5b/big_Welcome_Pic_4‌​-300x169.png"; $string_nova = explode("=", $string_antiga); echo $string_nova[0]; echo $string_nova[1]; echo $string_nova[2];`

Comment: me retornou o valor: `code #EXTINF:-1 tvg-id"" tvg-name"BBB 18 -Aquecimento" tvg-logo `

eu preciso que retorne somente o valor de tvg-logo

Comment: Isso é o que a **$string_nova** irá receber já indexando os campos. Agora você precisa acessar a posição correspondente que você necessita. Por exemplo, dê um **echo** em **$string_nova[2].** Verifique os exemplos que estão nos links da documentação que te enviei.

Comment: fazendo dessa forma ele me retonar isso `code "https://s9.postimg.org/4c14egx5b/big_Welcome_Pic_4-300x169.png" group-title `

veja que trouxe o group-title como remover e deixar somente a url ? deixei somente assim echo $string_nova[3]; para receber isso acima.

Comment: Entendi. Eu não consigo resolver esse problema. Você poderia aproveitar esse novo problema e criar outra pergunta que com toda certeza, irão te ajudar, ou editar no seu próprio post.

Comment: Obrigado Amigo!

Answer (score 0):

A resolução final para o que eu queria ficou assim:

```
$string_antiga = $array[10][0]; 

preg_match_all("/\"[^\"]*\"/",$string_antiga,$x);
echo '<pre>'; print_r($x);

echo $x[0][2];
```

obrigado a todos que tentaram ajudar.